# Configurations for content_main.xml must agree on the root element's ID

Tags: android, xml, layout, fragment

I am trying to add a fragment into a frame layout on a landscape view, but the runtime keeps coming back with:
Configurations for content_main.xml must agree on the root element's ID.

Missing ID:

- layout-land

@+id/fragment:

- layout

I can't seem to figure this one out, and it is frustrating. Full XML for fragment and Linear layout below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="com.example.tasktimer.MainActivityFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.tasktimer.MainActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/task_details_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two editions of `content_main.xml`:

- `res/layout/content_main.xml`
- `res/layout-land/content_main.xml`

The root XML element for those need to have an `android:id` attribute with the same value (perhaps for use with data binding or view binding). In your case, apparently they do not.

If your code snippet is supposed to be showing those two layout resources:

- One has a `<fragment>` as the root element, and it has `android:id="@+id/fragment"`
- The other has a `<LinearLayout>` as the root element, and it does not appear to have an `android:id` value, which does not match

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on how I can amend this. Prior to adding the landscape, I had no issues with the program, but now it is not working. What would a suggested fix be?

Comment: @PhillipPounds: First, identify what specifically in the build process is resulting in this error. My guess is that it is coming from data binding or view binding, but that is just a guess. I can see where those things might require the root element IDs to be the same.

Comment: The issue is, that the fragment in content_main, is the same fragment being used within the Linear Layout, co they have to have the same android ID.

Comment: in vertical it should show the content_main fragment, and in horizontal it should show the same fragment, with a container view to hold additional Add_Edit.. If I set the same android ID for both, then the android ID for the fragment changes. I have really been struggling with this one, as it seems logical to have both have the same ID, but when I do, i receive error code "Root bindings cannot be optional"

Comment: @PhillipPounds: That further suggests that you are using view binding or data binding. Those are useful tools, but they impose limits on your layouts. Try having the same top-level container in both layouts, even if in one layout the container is unnecessary.

Comment: Dude! Absolute life saver, thank you